# Can't scroll the ionic date time picker @ionic/React

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

I just add the IonDatetime in my ionic project and when I want to pick a date I can't scroll on each selector on Android. So I try on web with Ionic serve and it's work but I still can't modify the date on Android (try on a Samsung A3 and on emulator).

I use ionic capacitor 6.16.1

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './InscriptionContainer.css';
import { IonItem, IonLabel, IonInput, IonCheckbox, IonButton, IonDatetime } from '@ionic/react';

...

<IonDatetime  displayFormat="DD MM YYYY" > </IonDatetime>
```

If anyone got a solution, I can't try on ios for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in Capacitor, update to 3.0.1 version that was released yesterday.